# Error: Module 'Ssystem, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-mvc

I get this error and I don´t know why.

I get this error while I try to connect my database as follow:

```
public MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            _sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
            _sqlConnection.Open(); --in this line i get the error msg

            return _sqlConnection;
        }
```

is use MySql.Data and Dapper to connect it. i guess some dependence are missing or not correct, but i don´t know where i have to search for it. Following my csproj file (i know i don´t need entityFrameworkcore if i want to use Dapper. it´s still left and still removed):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper">
      <Version>1.50.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4">
      <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation">
      <Version>1.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Config" />
    <Folder Include="Data\abstract" />
    <Folder Include="Data\concrete" />
    <Folder Include="Data\Test" />
    <Folder Include="docker" />
    <Folder Include="Models\test" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\Views\Home" />
    <Folder Include="out\out\out\Views\Shared" />
    <Folder Include="out\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.6" />
    <Folder Include="out\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MySql.Data, Version=1.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Downloads\mysql-connector-net-1.0.10-noinstall\bin\MySql.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is that a Core library for MySQL? Which is not in nuget?  Only reason I ask it doesn't appear to be a version that is remotely available like as in really old or non-existent.  as for the EFC stuff you can cut it out if aren't using as well as the SqlServer stuff....